# AngularJS Rest GET request not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, parameter-passing

I am working on my Front End (Angular Js calling a Rest Service) and this is working fine , i get a nice JSON as response:

```
$scope.test = function(response) {  
    $http.get("http://localhost:8080/androbridge/test/dotest"+"?s=ssss").success(function(response){
    $scope.related=JSON.stringify(response);
});
```

While this is not working :

```
var x;      
    $http.get("http://localhost:8080/androbridge/einloggen/loggeEin?username=" + $scope.username + "&password=" + $scope.password).success(function(response)
            {x=JSON.stringify(response);})  

    if(x=={"Kennzeichnung":"login","Status":true}){
        $rootScope.loggedIn=true;
        $location.path('/userPage');    
}else {
    alert('Wrong Login Information'+$scope.username +$scope.password + x)
}
```

Anyone see what mistake i make? I cant figure it out!

Comment: what error do you see in console??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the variable x is inside the $http scope, while you are testing it outside. The http call is asynchronous. Try this:

```
var x;
$http.get("http://localhost:8080/androbridge/einloggen/loggeEin?username=" + $scope.username + "&password=" + $scope.password).success(function(response) {
    x = JSON.stringify(response);
    if (x == {
            "Kennzeichnung": "login",
            "Status": true
        }) {
        $rootScope.loggedIn = true;
        $location.path('/userPage');
    } else {
        alert('Wrong Login Information' + $scope.username + $scope.password + x)
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Sir! Works like a charm .

Answer (score 1):

First off, you can't do object comparison like this:

`if(x=={"Kennzeichnung":"login","Status":true}){`

You could instead do something like this:

`if(x.Kennzeichnung == 'login' && x.Status){`

Also the `$http.success()` method is deprecated. You should use `$http().then(successFn, errorFn);` instead.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, $http is asynchron so your if will be executed before the response get received. Next thing is your if statement, it's syntactically incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move all your code into the callback for the Promise. The promise callback is asynchronous and only get called once the response is coming back from the server. Your code block is currently outside the callback and will get executed immediately and not when the result is being returned.

Try something like this

```
    $http.get("http://localhost:8080/androbridge/einloggen/loggeEin?username=" + $scope.username + "&password=" + $scope.password)
.success(function(response)
            {

    var x = JSON.stringify(response);
    if(x == {"Kennzeichnung":"login","Status":true}){
        $rootScope.loggedIn=true;
        $location.path('/userPage');    
     }else {
      alert('Wrong Login Information'+$scope.username +$scope.password + x)
    };

});
```